# Magento grouped product options

Tags: magento

I want to show a set of products as a table inside one product with these attributes.

**Dimensions Width x Gusset x Height Code Price/Case Bags/Case Weight**

So i chosen grouped  product option but it does not match the requirement. How can i design a table like format from the grouped product option with radio button to choose only one product from it. So using grouped product or  configurable  product or by any way how can i achieve this.

Here am attaching the screen-shot which i actually wanted

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to represent this in code. If the dimensions tend to be from a limited set of choices, you could use a configurable product to represent this choice, simply displaying all possible sub-products in the table. This would let you reuse the existing catalog product page with a little retrofitting.

If they do not fit well, you could place the items in a category hidden from the public categories and loop through each of the products in the category to display the table. This would require more work to tie back to putting into the cart, etc.

Importantly, it looks like each of your options has an entirely uncorrelated price, so it seems to me that you need to have a simple product underpinning these options at some point. (I'm sure you could get more clever, I'm just not sure that's a good idea.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. yes i was thinking the category idea and as you said it will take more time, so am trying the configurable product option. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this with a plugin for Magento. There is a plugin here which will do exactly what you want. It will display product options in a grid: http://www.magemechanics.com/product-grid-options.html